# Alternative to FILTER with REGEXMATCH to get a working arrayformula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas

Is there a way to make below work as an arrayformula in Google Sheets? It works fine used in each row, but with 1k+ rows of data the sheet gets very slow.

```
=FILTER( L:L, J:J=A2, REGEXMATCH(K:K, B2))
```

From what I've learnt so far Filter doesn't normally work with Arrays, so any other alternatives are welcome. I couldn't make any soluion that I've found so far work with regexmatch function. Here's [EXAMPLE SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kfhhpzzEST5a8V1A8SRDWlk5Ih_7kYfr0GsgY8AbkKs/edit?usp=sharing) so you can see the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to return numbers, sumifs could be done with single formula:

```
=MMULT(ArrayFormula(--(A2:A13=TRANSPOSE(K1:K7))*
--(REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(L1:L7),B2:B13))),M1:M7)
```

To make this formula work for different arrays, use this construction:

- `A2:A13` → `offset(A2,,,counta(A2:A))`
- `B2:B13` → `offset(B2,,,counta(A2:A))`
- `K1:K7` → `offset(K1,,,counta(K1:K))`
- `L1:L7` → `offset(L1,,,counta(K1:K))`
- `M1:M7` → `offset(M1,,,counta(K1:K))`

[Example file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k4Li683qnPVK5QH_iz61go_LEs41rR9L9Vqytz56m-U/edit?usp=sharing)

---

I'm not sure, that it'll speed up your calculations. But this formula is easier to use (no need to drag down). Also you could use script to calculate formula, and then to copy formula results as values.

Comment: Thanks, Max! Works for me.

Comment: I was thinking to paste formula and then copy and paste values only using a script. Do you mean it can calculate formula within a script and then copy results into a sheet? Can you give me a hint where I can learn that?

Comment: I've made [short demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g_Lg1SQK0aNSCk1C3x7TPQ6WuHzwB8ZRjlNSs4Twj1s/edit?usp=sharing) with the script inside. You could possibly make it work. But better approach is to post another question to get more answers from script experts.